# BaseAdapter returns null

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I have a fragment with a foldingcell view

here is the mainfragment -

```
public class FriendFragmentMain extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = FriendFragmentMain.class.getSimpleName();
private FriendsCellListAdapter friendsCellListAdapter;
private List<FriendsItem> friendsItems;
private String URL_FRIEND="http://212.224.76.127/friends/friends.json";
private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
private Activity mActivity;
private ListView friendsListView;

public static FriendFragmentMain newInstance(){
    FriendFragmentMain friendFragmentMain = new FriendFragmentMain();
    return friendFragmentMain;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_fragment_main, container, false);

    friendsListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.friend_super_list);

    friendsItems = new ArrayList<>();
    friendsCellListAdapter = new FriendsCellListAdapter(mActivity, friendsItems);
    friendsListView.setAdapter(friendsCellListAdapter);

    friendsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            ((FoldingCell) view).toggle(false);
            friendsCellListAdapter.registerToggle(pos);
        }
    });

    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FRIEND);
    if (entry != null){
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFriend(new JSONObject(data));
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_FRIEND, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response:" + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    parseJsonFriend(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "ERROR:" + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    return view;
}

private void parseJsonFriend(JSONObject response){
    try {
        JSONArray friendArray = response.getJSONArray("friends");
        for (int i =0; i < friendArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject friendObj = (JSONObject) friendArray.get(i);

            FriendsItem item = new FriendsItem();
            item.setId(friendObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(friendObj.getString("name"));
            item.setProfilePic(friendObj.getString("profilePic"));
            item.setBackgroundImage(friendObj.getString("backgroundImage"));
            item.setStatus(friendObj.getString("status"));
            item.setWork(friendObj.getString("work"));
            item.setLocation(friendObj.getString("location"));

            String friendUrl = friendObj.isNull("website")? null : friendObj
                    .getString("website");
            item.setWebsite(friendUrl);

            friendsItems.add(item);
        }
        friendsCellListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}
}
```

the base adapter looks like this -

```
public class FriendsCellListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private HashSet<Integer> unfoldedIndexes = new HashSet<>();
private View.OnClickListener defaultMessageButton;
private View.OnClickListener defaultViewProfileButton;
private Activity activity;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<FriendsItem> friendsItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


public FriendsCellListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FriendsItem> friendsItems){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.friendsItems = friendsItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return friendsItems.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return friendsItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    if (inflater==null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    FriendsItem item = friendsItems.get(position);

    FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHoler;

    if (cell == null){
        viewHoler = new ViewHolder();
        cell = (FoldingCell) inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_cell, parent, false);

        viewHoler.profilePic = (NetworkImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.friends_profile_pic);
        viewHoler.clientName = (LoginTextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.client_name);
        viewHoler.friendStatus = (LoginTextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.friend_status);
        viewHoler.backgroundImage = (NetworkImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.friend_background_image);
        viewHoler.friendAvatar = (NetworkImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.friends_avatar);
        viewHoler.friendName = (LoginTextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);
        viewHoler.friendLocation = (LoginTextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.friend_location);
        viewHoler.friendURL = (LoginTextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.friend_url);
        viewHoler.friendWork = (LoginTextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.friend_work);
        cell.setTag(viewHoler);
    } else {
        if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)){
            cell.unfold(true);
        } else {
            cell.fold(true);
        }
        viewHoler = (ViewHolder) cell.getTag();
    }

    viewHoler.clientName.setText(item.getName());
    viewHoler.friendName.setText(item.getName());

    //chech for empty status
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())){
        viewHoler.friendStatus.setText(item.getStatus());
        viewHoler.friendStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHoler.friendStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //check for empty location
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getLocation())){
        viewHoler.friendLocation.setText(item.getLocation());
        viewHoler.friendLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHoler.friendLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //check for null url
    if (item.getWebsite() != null){
        viewHoler.friendURL.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+item.getWebsite()+"\">" + item.getWebsite()+"</a>"));
        viewHoler.friendURL.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        viewHoler.friendURL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHoler.friendURL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //check for empty work
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getWork())){
        viewHoler.friendWork.setText(item.getWork());
        viewHoler.friendWork.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        viewHoler.friendWork.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //profile pic
    viewHoler.profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);
    viewHoler.friendAvatar.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

    //background image
    viewHoler.backgroundImage.setImageUrl(item.getBackgroundImage(), imageLoader);

    return convertView;
}

public void registerToggle(int position){
    if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position))
        registerFold(position);
    else
        registerUnfold(position);
}

public void registerFold(int position){unfoldedIndexes.remove(position);}

public void registerUnfold(int position){
    unfoldedIndexes.add(position);
}

private class ViewHolder{
    NetworkImageView profilePic;
    LoginTextView clientName;
    LoginTextView friendStatus;
    NetworkImageView backgroundImage;
    NetworkImageView friendAvatar;
    LoginTextView friendName;
    LoginTextView friendLocation;
    LoginTextView friendURL;
    LoginTextView friendWork;
}
}
```

now when i run it it throws -

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                          at com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.fragments.FriendFragmentMain.onCreateView(FriendFragmentMain.java:60)
```

this error. i am unable to find out why its throwing a null object? can anyone throw a light on why its showing null object.

the views are here- friends_cell

```
    <com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:folding-cell="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    folding-cell:additionalFlipsCount="2"
    folding-cell:animationDuration="1300"
    folding-cell:backSideColor="@color/bgBackSideColor">

    <include layout="@layout/friends_content_layout"/>

    <include layout="@layout/friends_cell_title_layout"/>

</com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell>
```

friends_cell_title_layout -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<!--LEFT Part -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="155dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/feed_item_border">
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/friends_profile_pic"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<!--RIGHT Part-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/feed_item_border">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/from_to_purple"/>
    <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/client_name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/friend_profile_divider"
        android:layout_below="@+id/client_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
        android:src="@color/contentDividerLine"/>
    <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/friend_status"
        android:layout_below="@+id/friend_profile_divider"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and friend_content_layout -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <!--Content header line-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/text_password"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_icon"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Content header Image-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/friend_background_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Content body layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="9dp">

        <!--avatar and name-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/friends_avatar"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/friend_name"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/friends_avatar"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/friends_avatar"
                android:textColor="@color/mainTextColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/friend_location"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/friend_name"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/friend_name"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--Divider Line-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:src="@color/contentDividerLine"/>

        <!--Address Part-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/url_badge"
                    android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:text="WEBSITE"/>
                <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/friend_url"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/url_badge"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/url_badge"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainTextColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Divider Line-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:src="@color/contentDividerLine"/>

        <!--Work Part-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/work_badge"
                    android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:text="WORK"/>
                <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/friend_work"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/work_badge"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/work_badge"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainTextColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Buttons-->
        <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/friend_send_message"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/btnRequest"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Send Message"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/mainTextColor"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <com.evolustudios.askin.askin.src.customfonts.LoginTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/friend_view_profile"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/btnRequest"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="View Profile"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/mainTextColor"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your error logcat?

Comment: the below one worked - but now this shows up -

Comment: 09-08 11:53:50.813 2851-2851/com.evolustudios.askin.askin D/Volley: [1] 3.onErrorResponse: FriendFragmentMain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `friendsItems` before passing it to `friendsCellListAdapter`

```
 friendsItems = new ArrayList<FriendsItem>(); // add this line
 friendsCellListAdapter = new FriendsCellListAdapter(mActivity, friendsItems);
 friendsListView.setAdapter(friendsCellListAdapter);
```

Comment: comment here whats issue now?

Comment: D/Volley: [1] 3.onErrorResponse: FriendFragmentMain

Comment: i guess the Json is wrong somewhere

Comment: its not possible to figure out the issue with  
`D/Volley: [1] 3.onErrorResponse:` only this info if your current problem fixed you can try your best to figure out next issue if you failed to find issue post an other question here with complete info of newly occurred problem.

Comment: if this post helps you in any way you can tick mark and vote up thanks happy coding :)

Comment: [link](http://212.224.76.127/friends/friends.json) here is the file i am trying to read

Comment: why  a semi colon is missed in json after `"interest":"coding, gaming"`   ' ,' here?

Comment: i got it, tried it in JSONLint

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help